# Loose sketchy look

Tags: freestyle

I want to leave Sketchup and want to learn blender. But I love the loose sketchy look , that I get at Sketchup. Is it possible in blender 2.8?

[image]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Freestyle. look up some tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: definitely.

[image]

The long answer is.. too long. You're not to know it, if you're just starting Blender, but Freestyle, (the engine you'll be using to do this) offers so many ways to adjust where lines are drawn, and what style they have when they are, that it wouldn't be possible to cover them all in a BSE answer.

First Steps:

- (Sorry).. [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/index.html)
- Online tutorials: search terms like 'Blender Freestyle'.. 'Sketchy'
- A lot of informed playing with the system
- Asking in places like this one if you run into specific problems.

I may be corrected, but I think you'll get the quickest feedback on your experiments by sticking with the Blender Internal renderer in Blender 2.79. That way you'll be able to see the results of your adjustments in the viewport preview render, without having to make a full render every time you tweak.

[image]